# Comparison of lookup times: foreign key is or is not present

Tags: database, performance, oracle, join

A colleague recently described to me a plan to re-architect a database.  The new database will conform to a simple [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema): the parent table will consist of a key and some contextual information, and that key will serve as a foreign key field in other tables.  The foreign key field may appear in the same child table multiple times.

Pseudocode:

```
TABLE Parent
   INT key PRIMARY_KEY
   INT foo
   ...

TABLE Child1
   INT key FOREIGN_KEY REFERENCES Parent.key
   BLOB bar
   ...

TABLE Child2
   INT key FOREIGN_KEY REFERENCES Parent.key 
   VARCHAR tar
   ...
```

The motivation behind the design is to simplify JOINs between `Parent` and `Child<n>`, which was complicated with the previous schema.

In an effort to further speed up JOINs, my colleage wishes to minimize the use of OUTER JOINs.   Specifically, she wants to emulate OUTER JOINs by using JOINS and by maintaining the data in the children tables in a particular way: populating all of them such that for each `key` in `Parent`, there is at least one row in `Child<n>` with that `key` value, even if the row is otherwise full of `null`s.  This way, any JOIN performed between `Parent` and `Child<n>` on `key` would return at least one result for every `key` in `Parent`, much an OUTER JOIN.

Putting aside the question of whether or not maintaining the data in this way is worth the effort, is this approach more performant than doing OUTER JOINS, assuming all `key` fields are properly indexed and about half the childrens' rows are `null`ed out?

The question seems to boil down to "is faster to do an index lookup for a value that is present in the index rather than a value that is not present?" Assuming the index operates like a B-tree or a hash, the answer strikes me as "no," but I don't know enough to be certain.

Comment: not sure what you have there is a star schema.  A typical star would have a fact table (your "parent" I guess) and many dimension tables (your "children" I guess).  The fact would have the various dimension keys.  For example, a sales fact table might have keys for product_id, time_id, store_id, etc.  So not sure I understand your approach exactly

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I have not noticed major performance differences between outer joins and inner joins.  Why does your colleague believe that they are slower?

Adding additional records has two effects on performance.  The original data gets larger, requiring more pages to store the data.  This can have a large effect on performance, particularly if the additional pages (with no useful data) are competing for space with more useful structures (say the indexes).

The second effect is on the index.  It will need to be larger, which can result in a deeper index and more index pages.  Both of these can have an effect on performance.

There is another issue as well, not related to performance.  Users/developers writing queries would need to fully understand that these empty records exist.  It is quite easy to do a COUNT(*) or COUNT() and expect the result to accurately reflect the number of records with data.  If this isn't the case, you might cause coding problems down the road.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this method will improve performance.

Inner joins *are* usually faster than outer joins.  This is because inner joins are more restrictive, giving the optimizer more opportunities to reduce the result set earlier in the plan.

But if you artificially add data, your inner joins aren't more restrictive anymore.